# Pyqt4: Can you share an object between threads?

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, qthread

so I am working with an API that has an object that connects to another machine and dose some proprietary magic to get information and is used to change it. Lets call this object a scheduler. Now I can only have one of these objects in my application, however I have multiple threads that need access to this object. Can I "Share" this object between my threads with pyqt? If so how do I access it? If I have multiple threads trying to access it at the same time will the thread hang till it is able or will it fail out my app?

Comment: Why can't you pass that object to the other threads?

Comment: Obviously you *can* share any object you like between threads: just make it available as a global variable, or pass each thread a reference to it. The only real question is whether it is safe to do so, and that is impossible to answer without knowing the exact nature of the shared object.